# Fixing Output in Custom Tkinter Text Box

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, customtkinter

I have some working code that creates a GUI Interface.
There is a button that runs a job and sends some output to a Text box in the GUI.
The job is running fine but the output is coming out out of sync.
The code I am using for the Job is:

```
        def UK_VPN_Stats():
            u = username.get()
            p = password.get()
            with open('UK_ASA.txt') as uk_asa:
                for HOST in uk_asa:
                    ASA = {
                        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
                        'host': HOST,
                        'username': u,
                        'password': p
                    }
                    # Next establish the SSH connection
                    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ASA)

                    output = net_connect.send_command('sh vpn-sessiondb summary')
                    with open("asa_output-template.txt") as template:
                        fsm = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
                        result = fsm.ParseText(output)
                    for device_stats in result:
                        print_out.insert("end-1c", "Connecting to " + HOST + '\n')
                        print_out.insert("0.0", f"AnyConnect Client: {device_stats[0]}" + '\n')
                        print_out.insert("0.0", f"IKEv2 IPsec: {device_stats[1]}" + '\n')
                        print_out.insert("0.0", f"Total Active and Inactive: {device_stats[2]}" + '\n')
                        print_out.insert("0.0", f"Device Load: {device_stats[3]}" + '\n')
```

With this the output should look like this:

```
Connecting to device1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnyConnect Client: 181
IKEv2 IPsec: 1
Total Active and Inactive: 193
Device Load: 26%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connecting to device2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnyConnect Client: 164
IKEv2 IPsec: 0
Total Active and Inactive: 171
Device Load: 23%
```

But it is coming out like this

```
Device Load: 23%
Total Active and Inactive: 170
IKEv2 IPsec: 0
AnyConnect Client: 163
Device Load: 26%
Total Active and Inactive: 193
IKEv2 IPsec: 1
AnyConnect Client: 180
Connecting to device1

Connecting to device2
```

Any help clearing this us would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting the text at the start of the text widget rather than at the end. You're inserting at index `"0.0"` which tkinter will interpret as `"1.0"` since line numbers start at 1. If you want the text inserted at the end, use `"end"`.

```
print_out.insert("end", f"AnyConnect Client: {device_stats[0]}" + '\n')
print_out.insert("end", f"IKEv2 IPsec: {device_stats[1]}" + '\n')
print_out.insert("end", f"Total Active and Inactive: {device_stats[2]}" + '\n')
print_out.insert("end", f"Device Load: {device_stats[3]}" + '\n')
```